# which interface will be used for outbound if i have more than one interface?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I am new networking-related concept, Let say I have two networks like below

- network A (192.168.0.103/24) connected with interface A
- network B (192.168.1.55/24) connected with interface B

What will happen in the below scenarios

- If I make a curl request to 192.168.0.100, which of the above interface will handle the outbound and why?
- If I make a curl request to 10.31.17.25, who will handle the outbound. Will this packet will be dropped?

Is it possible to control the routing behavior?

Comment: Funnily enough, the routing table controls the routing behaviour. For your examples, very likely your default route. Have a look at `ip route` and `ip route get`.

Comment: @dirkt tnx for your response, can you post this as an answer so, that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your routing table. Type

```
ip route
```

or

```
route -n
```

If you have not messed up with the route, for your questions the answers would be:

- For 192.168.0.100, network A will be used because it is on the same subnet.
- For 10.31.17.25, it is impossible to tell. Routing table will tell you, which device is used as a default gateway device.

Lets take a look at the sample output from `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
```

The first line says that all traffic outside of my subnet will be sent to default gateway 192.168.1.1 via interface wlp1s0.

The line starting with 192.168.1.0 is saying that all traffic matching genmask 255.255.255.0 will be sent from interface wlp1s0 directly to destination.